# SQlite with Android

Tags: android

If I create the SQLite DB and tables with some data at the time of developement then build the apk of that app,Does that tables and data will remain the same when I install that apk on android Device?

Comment: Nope, to do so you have put your DB inside assets folder

Answer (score 1):

Please see below link for copy database from your assets folder.

[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should put your DB in the assets folder...

Comment: @Feradau,You mean after running the app on emulator  i just need to copy paste ma db file from file explorer to the asset folder in project..Is it so?

Comment: @Feradau,But if I keep the DB file in asset.Can  i access it with normal Database code or we need to change it to anything else

Comment: Yes you can access it the normal way. Just open it from /assets/... BTW: it's ferdau

Answer (score 0):

That is not the case..your database wont get ported on the device..

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you need to understand is that your application doesn't get ported with  a database. It will be created on the device when your application runs for the first time. That's why the `onCreated()` method runs just once.